# ImportError: cannot import name 'aiplatform' from 'google.cloud' even though aiplatform module is installed

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform

I am having troubles reaching aiplatform module from google.cloud

```
from typing import Dict

from google.cloud import aiplatform
from google.protobuf import json_format
from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Value
```

I have properly installed `pip install google-cloud-aiplatform` on my windows machine, everything checks. Still, I am getting this error `ImportError: cannot import name 'aiplatform' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)`

Have you ever been stuck on a case like this before?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I've been able to run it without problems, You probably need to check your IDE and your virtual environment, check that you're installing the library into your virtual environment and NOT for the whole system

Comment: I checked and it look good. Actually I installed the library like I did with all the others. Nevertheless, it does not seem to work...

Could that be related to the authentication? I have downloaded my checkpoint .json file from GCP and added it to systems variables. Should I do anything else at this point? @ObadaZayadneh

Comment: Hi @RaphaëlAmbit, Can you try using the import statement `from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1 as aiplatform`?

Comment: Did the above comment help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1 as aiplatform worked for me actually, but actual aiplatform doesn't for some reason.